# CodeIgniter's Input Class

Tags: php, codeigniter, xss

Can I use CodeIgniter's input class to xss clean GET data like this:

```
$somevar = $this->input->xss_clean($_GET['somevar']);
```

CodeIgniter's suggest that `xss_clean` method should be used for the submitted data.

I wonder whether $_GET vars are submitted or just visiting a URL.

So can i use it in that fashion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

$this->input->get()

This function is identical to the post function, only it fetches get data:
**$this->input->get('somevar', TRUE);**

The function returns FALSE (boolean) if the item you are attempting to retrieve does not exist.

*The second optional parameter lets you run the data through the XSS filter. It's enabled by setting the second parameter to boolean TRUE;*

Answer (score 1):

The GET array is unset by CI on startup because it uses the URI segments instead.

But you can use the xss_clean method on any var you want, just like your example, but you will find $_GET to be empty. The input class is available everywhere by default.